# Using the stack to solve decimal conversion

Tags: javascript, data-structures

```
function baseConverter(decNumber, base){

 var remStack = new Stack(),
     rem,
     binaryString = '',
     digits = '0123456789ABCDEF';

 while(decNumber > 0){
     rem = Math.floor(decNumber % base);【this line】
     remStack.push(rem);
     decNumber = Math.floor(decNumber / base);
 }

 while(!remStack.isEmpty()){
     binaryString += digits[remStack.pop()];
 }

 return binaryString;
}
```

【this line】is the book example.Is it necessary to use ?

if I want to change it to

`remStack.push(decNumber % 2)`

is it OK?

so that we have no need to use `rem` and `Math.floor(decNumber % 2)`.

Comment: You can inline the rem variable if you don't want it, but you should probably replace it with the entire rhs and not leave off the Math.floor bit nor change the 'base' var into a concrete number (2).

Comment: What is `Stack`? I don't believe this is part of Javascript. At least, Chrome doesn't seem to know it.